# Django - Exception Value: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, forms, variable-assignment

In a definition for saving a search word in a form i got stack. This definition gives the error " local variable 'form' referenced before assignment". on the line ( if form.is_valid():). I tried to reorder it but didn't succeed. Maybe this is very easy for more experienced developers.

```
def SearchCreateView(request):
    template_name = 'SearchCreateView_form.html'
    model = Search
    form_class = SearchCreateViewForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form = SearchCreateViewForm(request.POST or None, instance=search.user)
            print(form.errors.as_text())
            search = form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.search.user = self.request.search.user
            return render_to_response(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render_to_response(request, 'save.html', context)
    else:
        form = SearchCreateViewForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, 'SearchCreateView_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: This is a function based view, not a class based view, so you can't use `self`. After `search = form.save(commit=False)`, just do `search.user = self.request.user`. Finally you need to call `search.save()`.

Comment: Also, don't use `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. Use `render()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to define the form variable:

```
def SearchCreateView(request):
    template_name = 'SearchCreateView_form.html'
    model = Search
    form_class = SearchCreateViewForm

    form = form_class(request.POST or None)  # ADD THIS

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form = SearchCreateViewForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
            print(form.errors.as_text())
            search = form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.search.user = request.user
            return render_to_response(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render_to_response(request, 'save.html', context)
    else:
        form = SearchCreateViewForm(request.POST or None)
            return render(request, 'SearchCreateView_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank for yours reactions! Followed both and i accidentally deleted Mohit's reaction. Sorry for that, Mohit. ;( Now have an other issue: Cannot assign "''": "Search.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: @green Maybe try `form.instance.search.user = self.request.user` instead?

Comment: @green you can't delete another user's answer, Mohit deleted the answer himself.

Comment: @vyruss self.request.user or self.request.user.POST.get('user") gives "WSGIRequest" object has no attribute 'get'. Could this have something to do that i'm a superuser and not login as a user?

Comment: @green sorry, I meant to say `= request.user`

Comment: @green if this helped you at all, can you accept the answer please?